# ScrollRectToVisible function

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollview` and which contains `UIView` as a subview like,

[image: scrollview with uiview]

here i can able to drag the `UIView` inside the `ScrollView`, when the uiview goes to at **END RIGHT** or **END LEFT** the uiview disappears inside scrollview, after that i has to scroll the scrollview then i can able to see the uiview, here i need to **SCROLL THE `SCROLLVIEW`** when uiview comes at the rightside or left side, for that i used this code but not working.

```
[myscrollview scrollRectToVisible:myview.frame animated:YES];
```

Comment: tell me where do you use the above code? I mean in which method you put the line of code?

Comment: In drag method that is dragging the myview using the pangesture

Comment: try to use one property of scroll view contentoffset this will provide you the proper coordinates in scroll view to move ie just modify the myview.frame.origin.x and .y by adding the contentoffset.x and .y respectively.

Comment: If you want some code snippets just ask for it I will provide it to you as comment or as answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Please give some code.

Comment: will give it to you in while just wait for some time :)

Comment: `CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x += scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    frame.origin.y += scrollView.contentOffset.y;` use `frame` in `[myscrollview scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];` like this :)

Comment: Sorry. Its not working.If i drag myview to right side, scrollview scrolls very fast towards the right side.

Comment: ok then just remove the + from both of the statements and try again :)

Comment: as I am not able to test it now, sorry for giving you the suggestions atm :)

Comment: Sorry Its not working..If i drag the myview to the end of the scrollview.I need to scrolls the scrollview automatically.Please help me

Comment: ok will give you some other code after testing it this time it will work for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have used on UIButton (as it is already used in one of my application I dont need to write whole code again)

```
[cropRectangleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

The `cropRectangleButton` is one UIButton and the `imageMoved:withEvent:` method is as below

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint prev = lastTouchDownPoint;
    lastTouchDownPoint = point;
    CGFloat diffX = point.x - prev.x;
    CGFloat diffY = point.y - prev.y;

    UIControl *button = sender;
    CGRect newFrame = button.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x += diffX;
    newFrame.origin.y += diffY;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2*scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:newFrame animated:YES];
    button.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Here I change my contentSize of scrollView as it is very narrow to test that the scrollView is scrolling or not you don't need that line of code.

And when I drag the button left the scrollView is also automatically scrolled to the button frame to show the whole button try to implement this using UIView and if not possible just put one transparant UIButton on your view fully covered the view and you it to do the drag :)